# Count business days between 2 dates in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count business days between a certain date range in PostgreSQL.

My table:

```
|start_date |end_date |
------------------------
|2017-06-01 |2017-06-01| 
|2017-05-29 |2017-06-02|
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT pto.start_date, pto.end_date, 
SUM(CASE WHEN extract (dow FROM foo) IN(1,2,3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as theDIFF 
FROM (
  SELECT start_date, (start_date::date + (generate_series(0,end_date::date 
        - start_date::date)||'days')::interval) AS foo
    FROM pto
) foo inner join pto pto
on pto.start_date = foo.start_date 
group by pto.start_date, pto.end_date
```

My OUTPUT:

```
      |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
      ---------------------------------------------------
      |2017-06-01      |  2017-06-01    |        29     |
      |2017-05-29      |  2017-06-02    |        12     |
      ---------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output:

```
      |start_date(date)| end_date(date) |theDiff(integer)
      ---------------------------------------------------
      |2017-06-01      |  2017-06-01    |        1      |
      |2017-05-29      |  2017-06-02    |        5      |
      ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there any id or PK column?

Comment: why do you want to count instead of just computing it?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a function for calculating Business Days between two dates simmilar to networkdays excel formula. Doesn't support Holiday list yet.

```
create or replace function count_business_days(from_date date, to_date date)
returns bigint
as $fbd$
    select count(d::date) as d
    from generate_series(from_date, to_date, '1 day'::interval) d
    where extract('dow' from d) not in (0, 6) 
$fbd$ language sql;
```

Usage

```
SELECT issue_id, start_date, live_date, count_business_days(
    TO_DATE(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    TO_DATE(live_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ) as businessdays
    FROM atable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using (or showing us) a unique key, if you have more than one row with the same (start_date, end_date) you will get wrong results.

```
select start_date, end_date, 
       sum(case when extract (dow from dt) in (1,2,3,4,5) then 1 else 0 end) as thediff
from (
       select start_date, end_date, 
              generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day'::interval) as dt
       from   tbl
     ) t
group by start_date, end_date;
```

> ```
> start_date          | end_date            | thediff
> :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
> 2017-05-29 00:00:00 | 2017-06-02 00:00:00 |       5
> 2017-06-01 00:00:00 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00 |       1
> ```

```
select id, start_date, end_date, 
       sum(case when extract (dow from dt) in (1,2,3,4,5) then 1 else 0 end) as thediff
from (
       select id, start_date, end_date, 
              generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day'::interval) as dt
       from   tbl
     ) t
group by id, start_date, end_date;
```

> ```
> id | start_date          | end_date            | thediff
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
>  1 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00 | 2017-06-01 00:00:00 |       1
>  2 | 2017-05-29 00:00:00 | 2017-06-02 00:00:00 |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1317613fcdfa664386496ff4036056c2)*

Answer (score 1):

No need for generate_series, date arithmetic will do :

> ```
> create table tbl (start_date date, end_date date);
>
> insert into tbl values
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-01'),
> ('2017-06-17', '2017-06-17'),
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-12'),
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-13'),
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-16'),
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-17'),
> ('2017-06-01', '2017-06-18'),
> ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-12'),
> ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-13'),
> ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-16'),
> ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-17'),
> ('2017-06-03', '2017-06-18');
>
> SELECT start_date,
>        end_date,
>        ((end_date - start_date) - 
>          EXTRACT (isodow FROM end_date) + 
>          EXTRACT (isodow FROM start_date)) * 5 / 7 + 
>        least(EXTRACT (isodow FROM end_date),5) + 5 - 
>        2 * least(EXTRACT (isodow FROM start_date),5) theDiff
> FROM tbl
> ```
>
> ```
> start_date |  end_date  | thediff
> :--------: | :--------: | :-----:
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 | 1      
> 2017-06-17 | 2017-06-17 | 0      
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-12 | 8      
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-13 | 9      
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-16 | 12     
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-17 | 12     
> 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-18 | 12     
> 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-12 | 6      
> 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-13 | 7      
> 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-16 | 10     
> 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-17 | 10     
> 2017-06-03 | 2017-06-18 | 10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1fabfe514e379d69f550c695957cf6bb)*

Answer (score 1):

Number of business days from today until the desired date.

```
select count(*) week_days
from (
  select 
    getdate()+dt, 
    extract(dow from getdate()+dt) dow
  from(
    select 
      generate_series(
        1,
        datediff('days', getdate(), '2023-07-11 00:00:00.000'),
        1
      ) as dt
  )
) 
where dow not in (0, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually working solutions with date arithmetic (counting days elapsed, so if start_date = end_date, then the result is 0):

```
(end_date - start_date)
-- number of days, business and non-business
- EXTRACT (isodow FROM end_date)
-- number of days to sunday strictly before end_date
+ least(EXTRACT (isodow FROM end_date),5)
-- number of days to friday before end_date if end_date is week-end, else to end_date
- (7 - EXTRACT (isodow FROM start_date))
-- number of days from sunday strictly after start_date
+ greatest (5 - EXTRACT (isodow FROM start_date), 0)
-- add back number of business days from start_date to that sunday
- (end_date - start_date - EXTRACT (isodow FROM end_date) - (7 - EXTRACT (isodow FROM start_date))) / 7 * 2
-- remove week-ends between the two sundays (whole weeks)
```